# Get specific text between a certain tag in all files in a directory

Tags: bash, sed, tags

I have a few hundred `.txt` files in a directory that have the following format:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO> 33 </DOCNO>
<SOURCE> URL v.01 </SOURCE>
<URL> www.url.com/extension.html </URL>
<DATE> 2019/12/29/ </DATE>
<TIME>  </TIME>
<AUTHOR>  </AUTHOR>
<HEADLINE>
        The title is here 
</HEADLINE>
<TEXT>
        Text that I want
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

I would like to manipulate every single file so that the file would only contain the text between the `<TEXT>` and `</TEXT>` tags (i.e.`Text that I want`)

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to do what I need:

```
find /root/Desktop/data/data -type f | xargs sed -n '/<TEXT/,/<\/TEXT/p'
```

How can I do this using a bash script (preferably using `sed`)?

Comment: You mean between the `TEXT` tags, to be clear - correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For some reason they were not showing as a part of plaintext. @kabanus

Comment: That is because you can embed HTML in your post so `<>` should always be in a code block.

Comment: Works for me. Did you try running `find` and making sure you actually get a hit with the tags?

Comment: Also, consider dropping `xargs` for a pure `find` solution `-execdir sed -n '/<TEXT/,/<\/TEXT/p' {} +`

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately, the tags are still in place, and the changes are not made on the files.

Comment: Use `sed -n '/<TEXT>/,/<\/TEXT>/{//!p}'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove everything but the text between `TEXT` tags from your files, right? This is how you do that.

```
find /root/Desktop/data/data -type f -execdir sed -i '0,/<TEXT>/d;/<\/TEXT>/,/<TEXT>/d' {} +
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks Oguz!

Comment: Won't this leave the last </TEXT> and everything after it in the file since there won't be a matching opening <TEXT>?

Comment: @TylerMarshall nope. sed processes its input line by line, so in this case it will delete everything until either finding a line matching `/<\/TEXT>/`or hitting EOF.

Answer (score 1):

If there are at most one pair of the tags you are looking for and you don't want newline characters in the text:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /root/Desktop/data/data/*.txt; do
  echo $(cat "$file" | tr -d '\n' | sed -nE 's/<TEXT>(.*)<\/TEXT>/\1/p')
done
```